# Mysql regex doesn't start with alnum

Tags: mysql, regex

I am trying to remove records from my table which don't start with an alnum character. I've tried a number of different things but MySQL doesn't seem to play ball.

My current query is:

```
SELECT *
FROM central_store
WHERE DomainName NOT REGEXP '^[[a-z|0-9]]'
```

I've also tried the [`:alnum`](https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/mysql-cookbook/0596001452/ch04s08.html) option, but my results still return records starting with a 0-9. I know this is probably basic but please can someone explain what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your pattern does not work because of doubled brackets. `^[[a-z|0-9]]` matches the start of string (`^`) position, then `[[a-z|0-9]` match a `[`, or an ASCII letter, or `|`, or an ASCII digit, and then a `]`. So, it matches `a]` at the start of a string.

You can fix your pattern using

```
REGEXP '^[^a-z0-9]'
```

Or, use `^[^[:alnum:]]`, as POSIX character classes (like `[:alnum:]`) must be used inside bracket expressions:

```
REGEXP '^[^[:alnum:]]'
```

If you have default settings, `'^[a-z0-9]'` pattern will also match uppercase ASCII letters since by default MySQL regex search is case insensitive.

Note that `'^[^a-z0-9]'` matches

- `^` - start of the string
- `[^a-z0-9]` - any char other than an ASCII letter or digits (`[^[:alnum:]]` does the same, matches any char other than a letter or digit).

Comment: Sorry - both options still return urls starting with numbers :(

Comment: Yes, because `0-9` match digits. Do you only need to match entries starting with **letters**? Then use `'^[a-z]'` or `'^[[:alpha:]]'`

Comment: I want strings that don't start with numbers or letters

Comment: Ok, just add `^` after the opening bracket in bracket expressions to negate. If you need to also find empty records, you will need to use something like `^([^a-z0-9]|$)`.

Comment: Sorry - still no difference :(

Comment: Remove `NOT` since it negates the regex search result. Add sample strings you need to match and those you want to avoid matching. The current answer contains the right regex expressions to find *records from my table which don't start with an alnum character*

Answer (score 0):

"alnum" means "letter or digit".  Yet you say you don't want to start with a digit.  Which is it??

```
WHERE url RLIKE '^[[:alpha:]]'
```

says "starts with one letter, *not* a digit, *not* punctuation.

To find rows that "don't start with a letter":

```
WHERE url NOT RLIKE '^[[:alpha:]]'
```

If you need "starts with letter" and "continues with alnum":

```
WHERE url RLIKE '^[[:alpha:]][[:alnum:]]*$'
```

And add `NOT` to invert it.

(Since you say "url", I suspect you aren't interested in this.)